# Switching Database for the same mapped table

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I use Fluent NHibernate and have to work with archived data right now, where the same table exists on multiple MSSQL Databases. Depending on a user provided Date value, I have to connect to a different Database, whereas all Mapping information remains the same.

More specific : if the provided Date value is within the current year, use DB `CUR`, otherwise use an annual DB (2011, 2010, 2009,...).

Now there was a time when people told me that re-creating a SessionFactory over and over is quite an expensive thing to do, so I thought to myself that there must be a way to use the existing sessionFactory, Update my ClassMap (something like change Schema from "CUR.DBO" to "2011.DBO") and reconnect.

I tried mess with both FluentConfiguration and SessionFactory, but **<s>then I took an arrow in the knee</s>** couldn't find a way to refresh the mappings at runtime.

Will I end up creating a new SessionFactory? Or does anyone out there know a viable procedure to reinitialize (Fluent) NHibernate's mappings at runtime?

**EDIT:** One very important detail, the SqlConnection is provided externally, too. It provides access to all databases, meaning that, in theory, I'll never have to create Connections. So, basically what I have to do is create a SessionFactory for each Archive to update the Mapping's Schema information, pointing to another database. But this is exactly where I'm stuck.

Comment: Why not create 2 session factories?  One for the archive database and one for the production database.

Comment: We have one archive per year, so I'd end up creating around 10 at least. That's basically what, to my knowledge, I'll have to do, but hopefully there's a smarter way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your responses / comments. Actually I haven't found a way to reuse the session factory, so I ended up creating a lookup list for them as proposed. The following solution does what I need (change the database), we shall how it performs:

```
    private IDictionary<string, ISessionFactory> _sessionFactories;

    public SqlConnection Connection { get; set; }

    public ISessionFactory GetSessionFactory(string dbName)
    {
        if (_sessionFactories.ContainsKey(dbName))
        {
            return _sessionFactories[dbName];
        }

        FluentConfiguration cfg = Fluently.Configure().Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
                                                                .ShowSql()
                                                                .ConnectionString(c=>c.Is(Connection.ConnectionString)))
                                                      .Mappings(x=>x.FluentMappings.Add<MappedClassMap>());
        cfg.ExposeConfiguration(x => x.GetClassMapping(typeof(MappedClass)).Table.Schema = string.Format("{0}.dbo",dbName));
        ISessionFactory sf = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
        _sessionFactories.Add(dbName, sf);
        return sf;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's true that creating a session factory is a much more expensive operation then creating a session, so you certainly don't want to create one for every single query to a database.

However, in my experience, it only takes a few seconds at most.

I'd suggest you create a new one every time the users selects a different year.  If you give them good feedback while this is happening (maybe a dialog that says something like "Connecting to 2010 database", with a progress bar), they probably won't mind the wait.

And once you created one for a year, you could reuse it if they do more querying on the same year, so they'd only have to wait once per year being queried.

If session factory creation is taking too long, I've seen postings explaining how to save or cache the configuration to reduce creation time.  However, a quick google did not turn up any good links, so you might have to research that, or ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the it's enough if the sessionfactory is created for a single db. But while Opening a Session with Sessionfactory instance an overloaded method is available to give the dbconnection object where we can switch the DB's. Have verified it and it's working fine.